# cannot find package sveltejs/adapter-auto svelte.config.js

Tags: sveltekit

I am new to SvelteKit and have built an initial project from the SvelteKit docs. When the project opens I receive the following error when looking at index.svelte.

> Error in svelte.config.js
>
> Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package
> '@sveltejs/adapter-auto' imported from /Users/.../svelte.config.js

package.json File

```
"devDependencies": {
        "@sveltejs/adapter-auto": "next",
        "@sveltejs/kit": "next",
        "prettier": "^2.5.1",
        "prettier-plugin-svelte": "^2.5.0",
        "svelte": "^3.44.0",
        "svelte-check": "^2.2.6",
        "typescript": "~4.6.2"
    },
```

svelte.config.js File

```
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-auto';

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    kit: {
        adapter: adapter()
    }
};

export default config;
```

While the project builds it's throwing errors everywhere. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you do `npm install` first ?

Comment: I did non install.

Comment: @StephaneVanraes I did run npm install but I ran this in VS Code. See my answer below. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 50):

I am using VS Code for the project. The issue is related to opening the project in VS Code, opening a terminal, and running the `npm install` command.

It appears that `npm install` must be run in an application like Terminal on a Mac prior to opening the app in VS Code.

Comment: I had the same issue after running `npm install`. Restarting VSCode fixed it.

Comment: actually, just closing the project and reopening is enough. No need to restart whole Visual Studio Code.

Comment: This is cool and I have upvoted both the answer and the comment by @Diesel! I will share a cooler solution if you're using VSCode and needs a restart. From your terminal, once navigated to the desired location, use `code . -r` to restart the same instance of the VS Code window.

Comment: You do not need to restart VSCode or closing and opening the project. Just restart TypeScript server and you should be good to go :)

Ctrl + P -> TypeScript: Restart TS Server

Comment: Lol thanks! Would not have thought this was the answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue, edit `package.json`:

- remove line:

  > "@svelte:qjs/adapter-auto": "next",
- then run:
  `pnpm i @sveltejs/adapter-auto`
  You may replace `pnpm` with `npm` or `yarn`.
- then in `package.json`, will get something like:

  > "@sveltejs/adapter-auto": "1.0.0-next.55"

That solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

My node+npm version was outdated. Make sure you have the latest node version installed.